# Elm version 18, temporary upgrade?

Tags: elm

I'm currently using Elm version 17.1 and want to try an application that uses version 18. I'm on Ubuntu.
Is there a way to temporarily upgrade to version 18 and then revert afterwards?
Otherwise what is the best approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the npm package [elm-version-manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elm-version-manager) to install multiple versions of Elm alongside each other (with the command `evm install 0.18.0` or `evm install 0.17.1`) and switch which one is 'active' (with `evm use 0.18.0` or `evm use 0.17.1`) systemwide.

Answer (score 2):

you can use npm.  As without global flag, npm packages can be installed for local project folder.